# MVVM Light Multiple Data Contexts

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, mvvm-light

I am new to MVMM Light toolkit (note, I'm using Light on .NET 3.5). So far I am really starting to like the pattern save for two challenges.

- I'd like to have reusable XAML templates for certain types of pages in my application. Think of a movie ticket kiosk. Main content in the center but almost always a button somewhere on the screen to cancel or go back. I'd like to have reusable grid(s) where when I create a new page I basically import that grid layout and don't have to worry about the common bits and can just focus on my part. Doing a little research I feel like `<ContentPresenter>` might be the way to go here but it's still foreign to me.
- Assumign I succeed in my first challenge, I would think the data context for those common items (say a `Cancel` button) would be somewhere else other than that page's ViewModel to avoid a bunch of duplication of code. Is that best approach to take the individual controls and reference a different view model from the XAML? Something like...

  `<Button ... DataContext={Binding CommonStuffVM, Source={StaticResource Locator}} />`

Comment: Somewhat tangential question for an application with so many disjointed views - pages w/ the navigation service (navigation ui hidden) are the way to go right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Templates` or `DataTemplates` to create a reusable template defining how an object should look.

For example,

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MovieTicket}">
    <!-- Write the XAML for your Movie Ticket -->
</DataTemplate>
```

You can give your `DataTemplate` an `x:Key` to reference it specifically in an `ItemTemplate` or `ContentTemplate`, or leave it out so it will be used anytime WPF tries to draw a `MovieTicket` object

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MovieTickets}" />

<ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedMovieTicket}" />
```

For your second question, I think this would be a bad idea for individual controls, although its a common practice for complete sections of the program.

When using MVVM, your `ViewModels` are your application, not your UI.

If your window should display a list of `Movies` for the user to edit, and allow the user to Save or Cancel their changes, then your ViewModel should contain an `ObservableCollection<Movie>` and contain an `ICommand SaveCommand` and `ICommand CancelCommand`

You really want your View to only reflect your ViewModels, and not have them pulling the data they need from all over the ViewModel hierarchy.

Based on your question, you may be interested in a blog article I have about [Navigation with MVVM](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/) which uses code very similar to what you're asking about. It shows how to change the UI using implicit `DataTemplates`, and contains a complete code sample that you can download and look at to get a better idea of the MVVM architecture.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful links. The ICommand stuff makes sense. I'm still not sure how to get the DataTemplate working the way I want. So somewhere "globally" I can define a grid w/ some buttons, and then in each view I can "import" that grid and add controls to it? That's what I'm going for.

Comment: @Ternary `DataTemplates` are usually found in your application's `Resources` somewhere, and can be applied implicitly or explicitly. You can give them an `x:Key` and specify them by name when you want them (`<ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MyDataTemplateKey}" ... />`), or you can leave the `x:Key` off and give them a `DataType` attribute, and they'll be used automatically anytime WPF tries to draw an object of the specified data type, such as what I have in my answer.

Comment: thanks so much for the great info and patience with me. I created the template in my `App.xaml` resources and it works fine. Two challenges - my template references static resource styles in a `Skin.xaml` (Mvvm light gave me that starting point) and those bindings don't resolve. For now I just moved them into my App.xaml (I have bingger fish to fry). But, elements of the grid (say the background color) need to be bound to different styles when they're using. Is there a way for the `<ContentControl>` to modify the bindings of the template it's presenting?

Comment: @Ternary You can use a `DynamicResource` instead of a `StaticResource` to have WPF look it up after the application is running and has loaded all its `Resources`. And you might be better off asking a separate question about modifying the background color... I'm not sure I understand what you're asking and would probably need a code sample :)

Comment: Ah `DynamicResource` does the trick. You rock! I'll consider formulate my binding question w/ a sample. Thanks!